# Property [***] does not exist on this collection instance Laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Post Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And in the User Model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Now I am trying to get the comments of a specific user

```
$user= User::where('name', 'like', '%Mat%')->first();
return $user->posts->comment;
```

But it shows

> Property [comment] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user `has many posts` which therefore returns a collection, you will need to loop over this to get your comments out. I.e.

```
$user = User::where('name', 'like', '%Mat%')->first();

$user->posts->each(function($post) {
    echo $post->comment;
});
```

See the [documentation on Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
$user= User::with('post')->where('name', 'like', '%Mat%')->get();

$postComment = array();

foreach($user->post as $post){
  $postComment = $post->comment;
}
return $postComment;
```

Hope this help for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have **all** comments you can use the following code:

```
$comments = [];

$user = User::where('name', 'like', '%Mat%')->with(['post.comment' => function($query) use (&$comments) {
    $comments = $query->get();
}])->first();

return $comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Property [comment] does not exist on this collection instance.

The above error occurs because the Posts function returns a collection. Now you will have to traverse through each element of the collection.

Since, you are returning $user->posts()->comment, I am assuming you need it in the form of an array and don't have to simply echo them out, one by one. So you can store them all in an array & then process it whatever whay you like.

```
$comments = array();
$user->posts()->each(function $post){
    $comments = $post->comment;
}
return $comments;
```

For greater insight, into this collection function read:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each